# JS Data in asynchronous request undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, undefined

In this asynchronous function console.log(m) will return correct data, whereas console.log(m.w) will return "undefined" What's wrong? I'll be very appreciative of the clues. I've tested it with just `w:10, h10` so the problem is not in the server return.

```
var http = require('http');
var sizeOf = require('image-size');

async function asynchronousProcess(options){
    let m ={}
    await http.get(options, function (response) {
        var chunks = [];
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', function() {
          var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
          var data = {w: sizeOf(buffer).width, h: sizeOf(buffer).height}
          Object.assign(m, data)
        });
    });
    console.log(m)
    return m
}
```

Comment: you are mixing `async/await` and callback/event-based code. They don't mix together as you expect them to.

Comment: If `.get()` takes a callback then it won't return a `Promise` you could `await` for and `Object.assign(m, data)` is executed after `console.log(m)`

Comment: [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) returns a ClientRequest, not a Promise. Therefore there's nothing to await, and `console.log(m)` runs before the request ends. Use a module like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) instead.

Comment: You can also promisify your code: https://pastebin.com/92JXMQrV

Comment: Thank you @ChrisG You saved me!